# web3js RateLimiting my requests to the node

Tags: node.js, blockchain, web3js, rate-limiting

I need to ratelimit my requests to moralis speedy nodes (1500 req/min), I tried to make a counter with dates to limit it at 1450 but because my requests are async it does not work at all. Any suggestions?

here is my implementation if anyone is interested

```
let rate = 0
const rateLimit = () => {
  if (rate < 1450) {
    if ((rate = 0)) {
      time = Date.now();
    }
    rate = rate + 1;
    return true;
  } else {
    if (Date.now() - time > 6000) {
      rate = 0;
    }
    console.log("Rate limit reached");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: It's easier to catch the rate limit exception, then sleep some time, to throttle.

Comment: There is no rate limit exception, it just cancels the subscription to the node and the program stops, and I don't want to harass the node like that